# XCode still referring older framework

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode3.2

I'm using StakKit framework on my MacOX application, When I added newer version of the framework to the project. I have noticed that XCode is still referring to the older framework and I get warning like

> SKUser may not respond to '-gravatarIconURL'

How do I fix this issue? any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look through your framework search paths setting in the Target Info and see if you maybe have an older version of your framework in a higher priority search path than the one you have just added.  Also, check the header for the newer version of the framework to make sure the `gravatarIconURL` method is actually specified.